# adding typings to a imported json file

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

```
import { CharacterDataStructure } from "../../Typings/Interfaces"

declare module "../../Data/Characters/Raw_Characters.json" {
    export = CharacterDataStructure
}

import RawCharacters from "../../Data/Characters/Raw_Characters.json"
```

[image]
As you can see, I want to add a type to my JSON file but it recognises it as a non module. The reason why I want to do this is because of my interface,

Here is an example of my data in my json file and my interface:
JSON file:

```js
{ id: "character_1", type: "item" }
```

my interface:

```
interface CharacterDataStructure {
 id: `character_${number}`
 type: "item"|"power up"
}
```

When I import my JSON file, it recognises `id` and `type` as string(s) and does not check their value to see if they match the interface. And thus this will give me an error